# Ubuntu 16.10 Multiboot boots into Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have for some Days been trying to install the lates Ubuntu distro (16.10)
on my Win 7 Professional Desktop.
The "Test Ubuntu" runs properly.
The computer does not have UEFI.

When I install Ubuntu "Other ways" to a given free partition, Ubuntu does not manage to write the new Partion Table.  For example, I get an error that the /cdrom device is conflicting (yes, I am installing from CDROM).
I have tried different alternatives, starting out with "Alongside".
I have 2 HDs installed.

In the case when the installation completes succesfully, I reboot (without the CD) and Win7 is booted !
Using the Windows Tools for Disk Management, I can see no Boot or MBR partition.
The tool BDEasy says there is only one boot record (Windows).
I am a bit lost, thinking it might be some problem with my Win 7   installation.
Thinking of disconnecting my two drives and install a third HD, format it and install Ubuntu as singel (no multiboot).  Can I connect the Windows disk and then select the boot disk from the BIOS at start up ?
What are your suggestions to get along with Ubuntu ?

F.Y.I  I am not unexperienced with Linux installations, I did a lot of them as multiboot already at the Win95 era (Red Hat etc).
Regards Per Linden

Comment: I'm pretty certain the latest Ubuntu release is 16.10 and 14.10 is long since End-of-Life

Comment: If using 16.10 and 14.10 was typo. There have been mount issues. # Required as /isodevice usually mounts to a partition and installer does not correctly unmount   
`sudo umount -lrf /isodevice` 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1155216
Says to use toram boot parameter

Answer (score 0):

## I SOLVED my problem as follows :

1. Used BCDEasy to install a GRUB 2 multiboot manager.
2. Used BCDEasy to find the boot entry for Ubuntu.
3. Added the boot entry into the manager.

Now I have a working multiboot (Windows 7 and Ubuntu).
Thanks !